# Laravel / Eloquant: can i make relation mandatory while using "with" function in models

Tags: laravel-4, eloquent

I have a problem. I use the function `with()` for relating between models in Eloquent. Sometimes not all data exists in some model of the relationship, so it returns error, any solution?

For example:

```
Author::whereId($authorId)->with('AuthorContactData')->with('AuthorSocialLinks');
```

Sometimes `AuthorContactData` not exists for one Author. Is there any solution to ignore any author. How don't has `AuthorContactData`?

Thanks,

Comment: and also always use "with" at first Author::with('AuthorContactData', 'AuthorSocialLinks')->find($authorId);

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add that kind of constraint with `has()`:

```
Author::whereId($authorId)
      ->has('AuthorContactData')
      ->with('AuthorContactData', 'AuthorSocialLinks')
      ->get();
```